# Angular 6 generate the service in "e2e/app" folder

Tags: angular, angular6

I recently upgraded my angular 4 to 6.
now i tried below command

```
ng generate service security/security
```

but it created the service under the folder "e2e/app" instead under "src/app"
below is my angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "xyz": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/style.scss",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "test": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xyz:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "xyz:build:production"
            },
            "test": {
              "browserTarget": "xyz:build:test"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xyz:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/style.scss",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "xyz-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "xyz:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "xyz",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

I have recently upgraded from angular 4 to 6
when i tried in new app created using angular-cli ne new my-app command 
it is creating correctly in src/app folder

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the `angular.json` file, search for:  `my-project-e2e`

Replace `my-project` with your project name.

Changed:

```
  "root": "" to  "root": "e2e"
```

I found it here and it worked for me.

[Angular CLI 6 Component Generate Issue Solution](http://www.fwait.com/angular-6-cli-component-service-generate-issue/)